# Prevent inadvertently using different type class instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I expect the following behavior from the applicative instance of my `ZipList'`:

```
zipListApplyTest = fs <*> xs
  where fs = ZipList' [negate, id]
        xs = ZipList' [1..5]

-- Result: ZipList' [-1,2]
```

This was my first attempt:

```
newtype ZipList' a = ZipList' [a]
                   deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor ZipList' where
  fmap f (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ fmap f xs

instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipList' [x]

  ZipList' (f:fs) <*> ZipList' (x:xs) =
     ZipList' $ f x : (fs <*> xs) -- <-- the bug is here
  ZipList' [] <*> _ = ZipList' []
  _ <*> ZipList' []  = ZipList' []

-- Unexpected result: ZipList' [-1,2,3,4,5]
```

After some head scratching, I realized that inside the applicative instance of `ZipList'` I accidentally used the wrong `<*>`:

In the line marked with `the bug is here`, I applied the `<*>` that belongs to the built-in list type `[]` instead of applying `<*>` of `ZipList'` recursively.

This is why the second function `id` was applied to the entire rest of the list, instead of only the second element, `2`.

This yielded the expected result:

```
ZipList' fs <*> ZipList' xs = ZipList' $ zipApply fs xs
  where zipApply :: [(a -> b)] -> [a] -> [b]
        zipApply (f:fs) (x:xs) = f x : zipApply fs xs
        zipApply _ _           = []
```

Is there a compiler flag, language idiom, or other technique that would have prevented this bug or would have made it easier to spot?

I'm on GHC 8.2.2.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean with "I applied the `<*>` that belongs to the built-in list type?"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: In the line where it says `the bug is here` the apply method (`<*>`) of `[]`'s applicative type class instance is called. With "built-in" I meant the list type from `base`.

Comment: On a tangential note, `pure` for `ZipList` should be `repeat`, and not `(:[])` -- to see why, try to verify the applicative laws. (Great question, by the way!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
-- at very top of file ^
-- ...
-- pick whatever names/operators you want
-- synonym signatures are given in GADT-like syntax
-- ZCons decomposes a ZipList' a into an a and a ZipList' a
-- (assuming it succeeds). This is the syntax even for pattern synonyms that
-- can only be used as patterns
-- (e.g. pattern Fst :: a -> (a, b); pattern Fst a <- (a, _)).
pattern ZCons :: a -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' a
-- xs needs to be a ZipList', but it's only a [a], so we uglify this synonym
-- by using the newtype wrapper as a view
pattern ZCons x xs <- ZipList' (x:(ZipList' -> xs))
-- views aren't in general invertible, so we cannot make this an automatically
-- bidirectional synonym (like ZNil is). We can give an explicit version
  where ZCons x (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ x:xs
-- simple enough that we can use one definition for both pattern and expression
pattern ZNil :: ZipList' a
pattern ZNil = ZipList' []
{-# COMPLETE ZNil, ZCons #-}
-- ZNil and ZCons cover all ZipLists

instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipList' $ repeat x
  -- these are bidirectional
  (ZCons f fs) <*> (ZCons x xs) = ZCons (f x) (fs <*> xs)
  _ <*> _ = ZNil
```

Comment: Ohh, I did not know about `COMPLETE` ! Very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a variant of AJFarmar's answer, you can keep your definition of `ZipList'` exploiting a `[a]` list inside, and instead declare pattern synonyms to *pretend* the type was declared as

```
data ZipList' a = ZipCons a (ZipList' a) | ZipNil
```

In that way, if you limit yourself in using these "pretend" constructors when you write your instances, you can not inadvertently involve a list.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module ZipList where

newtype ZipList' a = ZipList' { unZipList' :: [a] }
                   deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Here are the pattern synonyms. We need to be a bit careful here since we need to convert lists to zip-lists as needed.

```
pattern ZipCons :: a -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' a
pattern ZipCons x xs <- ZipList' (x : (ZipList' -> xs))
  where ZipCons x xs = ZipList' (x : unZipList' xs)

pattern ZipNil :: ZipList' a
pattern ZipNil = ZipList' []
```

We can leave the functor instance as it was, exploiting the `Functor []` instance. Here, we do want to call the list `fmap`. Otherwise, we could use the "pretend" constructors, but we'd have to re-implement it.

```
instance Functor ZipList' where
  fmap f (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ fmap f xs
```

Finally, the applicative instance can use only the pretend constructors.

```
instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipCons x ZipNil

  ZipCons f fs <*> ZipCons x xs = ZipCons (f x) (fs <*> xs)
  _            <*> _            = ZipNil
```

To me a major downside of using the pattern synonyms is that the exhaustiveness checker gets easily confused, triggering spurious warnings. Above, if we replace the `_ <*> _` case with the two obvious cases involving `ZipNil`, we trigger a warning.

(Update: HTNV used a `COMPLETE` pragma to silence the warning, which looks very nice! I did not know about that.)

Apart from that, pattern synonyms allow to offer a quite elegant interface. I wish they were used more often in the Haskell ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prevent this in general. You must simply write your instances carefully.

That being said, one quick way to work around this problem would be to redefine your datatype; instead of putting it in terms of lists, make a new list type:

```
data Ziplist a = Nil | Cons a (Ziplist a)
-- (Instances etc follow)
```

This avoids the possibility for this kind of error. However, this isn't necessarily the best idea, since this requires function rewrites and so on.

You could just write tests. Which is best. So write tests. [HSpec](https://hspec.github.io/) is the most used test framework as far as I'm aware, so that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a general answer, but in this particular case I think by far the best and easiest thing is to just use `zipWith`, which is what the `base` library does.

```
instance Applicative ZipList where
  pure x = ZipList (repeat x)
  ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs = ZipList (zipWith ($) fs xs)
```